In 'perform MOK management' interface, wrongly choose 'continue reboot', what to do
When Ubuntu installs the NVIDIA graphics card driver, because I chose Continue Reboot in the Perform machine-owner-key Management interface, the driver cannot be used, and when I reinstall the driver, this interface does not pop up again, is there any alternative solution?I'm using a laptop with a dual system installed。
Tried reinstalling the driver，The tried driver versions are NVIDIA-driver-525,535,545,470. I hope that the driver can be called normally。

Please ask on Ask Ubuntu. This site is only for programming-related questions.
